# route.setRouter(app) ^ TypeError: route.setRouter is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am having this issue
route.setRouter(app)
TypeError: route.setRouter is not a function
in the cmd
this is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const appConfig = require('./config/appConfig');
const socketLib = require('./app/libs/socketLib');
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// require routes
const routesPath = './app/routes'
fs.readdirSync(routesPath).forEach(file => {
    if (~file.indexOf('.js')) {
        let route = require(routesPath + '/' + file);
        route.setRouter(app);
    }
});
```

and i have already installed express

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set up the routes the other way round, i.e. through `app.use(router)`

For example if your router-module contains the following:

```
/* router-test.js */
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Test from router')
})

module.exports = router;
```

Then, you can set up the router as follows:

```
const testRouter = require('./router-test');
...
app.use(testRouter);
// alternatively you can plug your router in beneath a path:
app.use('/somePath', testRouter);
```

So in your case you should probably do (note that I've changed the bitwise `~` and `.indexOf()` by the much simpler `.includes()`):

```
fs.readdirSync(routesPath).forEach(file => {
    if (file.includes('.js')) {
        let route = require(routesPath + '/' + file);
        app.use(route);
    }
});
```